# Is it a way to cancel an already running azure logic app grammatically or using HTTP call

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an azure logic app that do some work and it make a delay for 10 minutes then do another couple of things.

I already calling this app from an azure function and everything is works OK.

Now i have a requirement to terminate the already running logic app based on specific events during the 10 minutes duration.

I took a look on logic apps documentation and here in SO logic apps questions but there is nothing about this.

So, is it a way so I can cancel the already running logic app pragmatically or via HTTP call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to make

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/runs/{runName}/cancel?api-version=2016-06-01
```

as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowruns/cancel

Comment: how can I get the runName? I run my logic app by http request trigger but this not returen runName

Answer (score 4):

Based on my understanding, you can first use Logic Api to get all the workflow runs

```html
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/runs?api-version=2016-06-01
```

Then you can based on the response to cancel all the running workflow.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using HTTP request trigger, You can find the runName in response header.

[image: workflow run name]

Answer (score 1):

Same as mentioned in other answers but with simplified authentication doing the request directly from microsft.learn website and adding some basic parameters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflow-runs/cancel?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0

Use these values:
[image]

To fill this form:
[image]

Then just run the request.
Hope it helps.